# Shorthand CSS is not same as longhand

Tags: css, shorthand

As I said in the title, this shorthand:

```
.settingsSelect {
    background: url('../images/Custom.Select.Background.png'), url('../images/Settings.Input.Background.png') no-repeat, repeat 97%, 0;
    background-size: 12px, contain;
}
```

is displayed as

[image: bad shorthand]

and with proper longhand:

```
.settingsSelect {
    background-image: url('../images/Custom.Select.Background.png'), url('../images/Settings.Input.Background.png');
    background-position: 97%, 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat;
    background-size: 12px, contain;
}
```

everything works as expected.

[image: longhand]

Where is the problem? Thanks.

Comment: Are these commas supposed to be there (in the `background` shorthand) ?

Comment: on the shorthand, you have 3 commas, which makes 4 background-image ... lucky it even works ....

Comment: @Taurus I hope so. There are two images - secondary image is used as overlay for first one.

Comment: Did any of the solutions work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax in the shorthand version is incorrect. It should be:

```
.settingsSelect {
  background: url('../images/Custom.Select.Background.png') no-repeat 97%, url('../images/Settings.Input.Background.png') repeat 0;
}
```

Think of it as this:

```
.selector {
  background: background1, background2, background3, etc;
}
```

where `background1`, `background2`, etc are each a shorthand `background` of:

```
url() repeat X%;
```